# silent the undefined variable error in underscore.js

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a backbonejs app in which there are add and edit forms which are very similar. I am using same template for both add and edit operations. So in the template i have something like

```
<input type="name" value=<%= name %>
```

This will work fine when supplied with value name (in case of edit) but not in case where no value is supplied (in case of add). So i need to suppress the error generated in this case so i can use the template for 'add' purpose.

Tried this:

```
<input  <% if(item.name)%> value="<%= item.name %>" <% else %> value="" <% end %>  type="text">
```

But gives the error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: end is not defined
```

What can be the solution. I don't see any point generating a big template again provided its already available.

Comment: There is no keyword `end` in Javascript. You should be able to remove that and it would work.

Comment: tried using this: value="<%= company ? company : '' %>" in one of my forms. Doesn't work. It says company is not defined.

Comment: You're going to need to post your render code. I'd suspect as the error indicates that there isn't a company property on the object you're rendering.

Answer (score 0):

```
<% if (name) { %>
    <input type="name" value=<%= name %> >
<% } else { %>
    <input type="name" value=''>  
<% } %>
```

Comment: try now. I was using Ruby syntax ..bah!

Comment: tried using this: value="<%= company ? company : '' %>" in one of my forms. Doesn't work. It says company is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" value="<%= item.name ? item.name : '' %>">
```

Comment: tried using this: value="<%= company ? company : '' %>"  in one of my forms. Doesn't work. It says company is not defined.